# Wordpress Display All Sub categorys + posts under Posts Child Category in Sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, sidebar

Sorry for the complicated title.

I am working with this code, to display my sub child categorys with posts under them. The problem is that the code is displaying ALL Sub child categorys (+ posts) that I have on the site. I only want to show the Sub categorys that have connection with the post. All Sub child categorys under Child one have connection with the posts, so you can say I want to display the sub child categorys under child on becuse the post is related with child on.

Category structure (Year is in the title):

- G

  - Child 1

    - Gaming Year 1

      - Post for here
    - Gaming Year 2

      - Post for here

My code:

```
<?php
$cat_id = get_query_var( 'cat' );
$subcats = get_categories( 'child_of=' . $cat_id ); // child categories

class Cat_Walker extends Walker_Category {
    function end_el( &$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $posts = get_posts( 'cat=' . $page->term_id );

        if ( sizeof( $posts ) > 0 ) {
            $output .= '<ul>';

            foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
                $output .= sprintf( '<li><a href="%1$s">%2$s</a></li>', get_permalink( $post->ID ), $post->post_title );
            }

            $output .= '</ul>';
        }

        $output .= '</li>';
    }
}

foreach ( $subcats as $subcat ) {
    $subsubcats = get_categories( 'child_of=' . $subcat->term_id ); // sub child categories

    foreach ( $subsubcats as $subsubcat ) {
        $args = array(
            'title_li'         => '',
            'show_option_none' => '',
            'taxonomy'         => 'category',
            'child_of'         => $subsubcat->term_id,
            'walker'           => new Cat_Walker( )
        );

        wp_list_categories( $args );
    }
}

?>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting the wrong Category ID.  You should use this:

```
$category = get_category(get_query_var('cat'));
$cat_id = $category->cat_ID;
```

Instead of

```
$cat_id = get_query_var( 'cat' );
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! Well It's getting the right cat_id, the only thing is that it is printing all sub child categories on the website, I want to print all sub categories the posts is related to, in this case it's the  parent of the sub childs (child 1). How do I make the code do that?